# Null reference when using model value in the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nullreferenceexception

I am declaring my values in web.config

```
 <appSettings>
    <add key="SystemName" value="RealState Premium" />
    <add key="SystemDescription" value="Sistema de Administração Imobiliário" />
  </appSettings>
```

Configured a model:

```
    public class _Header
    {
        public string SystemName { get; set; }
        public string SystemDescription { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult _Header()
    {
        HomeModels._Header headerModel = new HomeModels._Header();

        headerModel.SystemName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SystemName"];
        headerModel.SystemDescription = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SystemDescription"];

        return PartialView(headerModel);
    }
```

and for the last, View:

```
@using realstate.Models
@model HomeModels._Header

<div class="logo">
    <img src="~/Images/logo/logo.png" alt="Mercado de Imóveis" />
    <table class="sysTitleTbl">
        <tr>
            <td class="name">@Model.SystemName</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="description">@Model.SystemDescription</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The problem is that I am getting a null reference in @Model.SystemName
What would be the problem?

Comment: What is the location of the Web.Config you placed the appSettings into relative to the root of your project? They must be placed into the web.config at the root; if you placed them into a config inside a Views folder, they will be irrelevant.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set break point to these line of code

```
headerModel.SystemName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SystemName"];
headerModel.SystemDescription = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SystemDescription"];
```

to see what' s happening with it

Comment: Thanks, I found that there were a error on the sequence of the calls.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are setting the appSettings node in the "/web.config" file and not the "views/web.config" file. Also, make sure that it sits within "configuration".

**Example:**

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="SystemName" value="RealState Premium" />
        <add key="SystemDescription" value="Sistema de Administração Imobiliário" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```